# Android studio BUILD FAILED In my Application shows error java.io.IOException: Could not delete path

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path

Myapplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\profilers-transform\debug\jars\1\10\226ac48e5c8c6b8707c7d76c6056e5800dee24de.jar'
```

I have use android studio 2.4.
please suggest solution regarding above issue,thanks in advance!

Comment: `Build -> Clean Project or Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: i have already did.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the directory or the file manually.

Comment: i have try to delete manually but i cant deleted that jar file, i also try after closed android studio but that jar file not deleted. i have use android studio 2.4

Comment: restart as administrator. that should do it.

Comment: I get this error randomly several times per day, mostly restarting the build solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess some of the files in the target build directory is open in another tool you use. Just a file handle open in the folder which has to be cleaned. The build task 'clean' wants to delete all the files in the build directory(normally 'target') and when it fails, the build fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, tried deleting the directory It didn't work. So this is what I did. I just copied all my project files except the "Build folder and "Build Folder" in App to a new directory and I opened the project from the new directory and it worked perfectly.